# Add a new row at the top of the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have created the table and I have one row with heading version app num and for that column I have given the some link to download that version app. But if anyone has uploaded a new version of the app on the server, in the HTML page that link has to come in the first row and the older version should be in the second row.

How to implement this? Do we need to implement anything in HTML, or do they need to change something server side. I have not been given any limit for the number of rows in the table.

My code is below:

```
<table border = "2" align= "center" cellpadding = "10">
<tr>
<th> Date </th>
  <th> Build No </th>
<th colspan="2">Production </th>
  <th colspan="2">Staging </th>
 </tr>
   <tr>
<td>date</td>
<td>1.5</td>
<td>Prod With Simulator</td>
<td>Prod WithOut Simulator</td>
<td>Stag With Simulator</td>
<td>Stag WithOut Simulator</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>date</td>
<td>1.5</td>
<td><a href= "http://some ur/">Download here</a></td>
<td><a href= "http://some ur/">Download here</a></td>
<td><a href= "http://some ur/">Download here</a></td>
<td><a href= "http://some ur/">Download here</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post some code and use some of those: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: It will be great if you post it to http://jsfiddle.net/. Helpful to work along with it.

Comment: @verisimilitude stackoverflow.com should not depend on jsfiddle.net. The code is to be posted *here* primarily if answers are desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant connect html to database .. in jsp we can connect so u write your html in jsp and connect the database... roseindia.com(see the database connection)

Answer (score 0):

you should use database... if anyone upload new version it should store in database from your database you should iterate and display the tables dynamically

Comment: thank u. how to connect the html to the database. or do i need to use the java class for connecting the database